# Effect of Work Items on Computation

Tags: opencl

I know that the number of Work Items affect the run time but should I expect to have slightly different results by using different number of work items while running a kernel many times? Thanks

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive about what "slightly different" means in this context. Are you talking about floating point values? Could you give some indication of the relative and absolute errors you are seeing?

Comment: What in the who at the where now? Please clarify what you're asking here.

Comment: I wrote a code both for CPU and GPU. which iterates over elements in a vector and then finds the norm. But with the same number of iterations I get slightly different norms. Is it because I use float in OpenCL and not CL_float?

Answer (score 0):

If you get different *results*, then you have a bug in your code. If you just do `norm+=element*element;` for a global variable `norm`, what will happen is that some threads do this at the same time and part of your norm gets lost.

To make things simple, this even happens when two work items increase the same counter, `a++`. Both will read the current value of `a`, both will increase it to `a+1` and both will write `a+1` back to the register. So you end up with `a+1` instead of `a+2`. What happens is similar for your vector.

Comment: Thanks but I found the problem. My method is sensitive to the order of work items.